# How to open a fileDialog to select a folder in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to open a file dialog to and **select a folder**, not a file, when i click on a button in a web browser using ASP.net.

Please let me know if there are any tags that i can use in .cshtml files or how to achieve it using C#.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: With what the browsers provide out of the box, i do not think this is possible. You need to have something like silverlight / java applets (does that still exist?) which can run on the client computer and have permission to access the file system.

Comment: I think we have some tags that can be used in **cshtml** files to open fileDialogs

Comment: you need folder browser not file dialog to select a folder. even then, not all browsers support folder selection. There's a webkitdirectory attribute, which is obviously only supported in webkit-compatible browsers.

Comment: Thanks @ShengJiang蒋晟 ... i am working on a test project which select the files from a folder and this works....
However is there a way where i can choose a folder when specific path is provided in a webpage.